# The role of "being" next to set verb

Tags: word-usage

What is the word **being** role in sentence?

> with all but the low-order bit being set to 0

There is a set verb in the past. Is there a need in being word?

Comment: Yes, there is a need _for_ the word 'being' in the sentence. _Being set to 0_ describes the state of all the other bits(?). _Set_ isn't in the past tense, it's a participle describing how they are when someone has set them to zero.

Comment: This doesn't feel like a complete sentence. Is there more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **being** is optional in this sentence. You can say either:

> ... with all but the low-order bit being set to 0

or

> ... with all but the low-order bit set to 0

There are many different types of usages of the word **being**. [Here's a reference](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv197.shtml#:%7E:text=We%20use%20being%20with%20the,garage%20is%20servicing%20my%20car.) that summarizes many of them.